# What's the spectrum of the operator $g\longmapsto f\cdot g$?

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the spectrum of the operator: $$T: C[0, 1]\longrightarrow C[0, 1], g\longmapsto f\cdot g$$ where $f\in C[0, 1]$ is a fixed function?

Here I'm considering the space $C[0, 1]$ endowed with the norm $\displaystyle\|f\|_\infty:=\sup_{x\in [0, 1]}|f(x)|.$

**Sketch:** I already know that: $$\sigma(T)=\textrm{im}(f).$$ The inclusion $\subset$ is fairly easy to show: If $\lambda\not\in \textrm{im}(f)$ then we might define the inverse of $T-\lambda I$ as the bounded and densily defined map: $$g\longmapsto \frac{1}{f-\lambda} g,$$ where $f-\lambda$ stands for the function $$x\longmapsto f(x)-\lambda.$$ Therefore $\lambda\in \rho(T)$ (where $\rho(T)$ is the resolvent set), equivalently, $\lambda\not\in \sigma(T)$.

The problem is the reverse inclusion. If $\lambda\in \textrm{im}(f)$ then $T-\lambda I$ is still injective if $f^{-1}(\lambda)$ is a discrete set so that $$T-\lambda I: C[0, 1]\longrightarrow \textrm{im}((T-\lambda I)),$$ is bijective.

Now it suffices showing the inverse is not bounded or is not densily defined, that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda \in \operatorname{im} (f)$, say $f(t_0) = \lambda$, then it follows that

$$\bigl((T-\lambda I)g\bigr)(t_0) = 0$$

for all $g\in C([0,1])$.

Then $\operatorname{dist}(1,\operatorname{im}(T-\lambda I)) \geqslant 1$, so $\operatorname{im}(T-\lambda I)$ is not dense.